# total number in field cannot exceed a value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

How can i tell oracle apex that the sum of a field (personal) cannot exceed 5 (5 being the total number of the field).  so example somebody could take up to 5 personal days but cannot exceed it other than that they have to use vacation

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

- create a function (which accepts person's ID) and returns total number of personal days (that would be a simple `SELECT` statement with a `SUM` function) and - probably - a `WHERE` clause that restricts rows to ... what? The last year?
- on Apex page, create a validation for item you use to enter number of personal days; its type would be a PL/SQL Function which returns error text, and checks whether number of entered personal days + total number of personal days (so far) (returned by a function) exceeds 5 days. If so, display an error.

Comment: can you help me with the coding for the above?

Comment: I'm glad if you did.